# Conversion failed when converting date and /or time from character string

Tags: c#, asp.net

It seems error is appearing to convert the date or time. I have two files result.aspx and result.aspx.cs. The data will be displayed according to the given 1 day previous date in text box. But it showing error. More detail about error see this url http://playrajshrirashifal.com/result.aspx. Also you can download the code from here. 
http://playrajshrirashifal.com/test.zip

result.aspx code

```
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList3" runat="server" DataKeyField="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

 <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" DataKeyField="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">

 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:rajshriConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [LotteryA], [LotteryB], [LotteryC], [Time], [Date] FROM [lottery] WHERE ((CAST([Date] as DATE) = @Date) AND (CAST([Time] as TIME) <= @Time))">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label2" Name="Date" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label1" Name="Time" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />

               </SelectParameters>
           </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:rajshriConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [LotteryA], [LotteryB], [LotteryC], [Time], [Date] FROM [lottery] WHERE ((CAST([Date] as DATE) = @Date) AND (CAST([Date] as DATE) < @Date2))">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="Date" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label2" PropertyName="Text" Name="Date2" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>

            </SelectParameters>
           </asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
```

result.aspx.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class result : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("t");
        Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");


    }


    protected void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataList3.Visible = false;
       asd.Visible = false;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You must add a globalization section to the Web.config file, and then set the uiculture and culture attributes, as shown in the following example:

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />
```

[Table of Language Culture Names, Codes, and ISO Values Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx)

Comment: Are you run in debug mode? Add in Web.debug.config.